# qTip2 'tip' (arrow) not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I'm having trouble creating working qTips (the little arrow isn't showing). I have had these working in the past; the only thing I can think that has changed over time is the jQuery and qTip2 versions. I am using the following code to generate the tip and have set up a test case here using the "latest" jQuery (1.10.2) and qTip2 (2.1.1) and it doesn't work for me (firefox, chrome):

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
     $('#testElement').qtip({
         content: 'readyTip'
     });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KgSqV/

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I see that your css reference is not complete version (seems to be partial); try change your include reference in the following:

- `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.1.1/jquery.qtip.js`
- `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.1.1/jquery.qtip.css`

It's partial because is the js/css `Basic features` version (no additional styles or features) you must use the `All features & styles`.

Download page: http://qtip2.com/download

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Pu4A4/

Comment: Those are exactly the two links I used in my case (I got them from http://qtip2.com/download). Correct me if I'm wrong but the only thing you seem to have done different is specified jQuery 1.8.3 in the "Frameworks and Extensions" part of JSFiddle. I've changed my JSFiddle to do the same and it still doesn't work while yours works perfectly, so I am even more confused now!

Comment: You are using the basic version so: Basic features (no additional styles or features) that is the problem!

Comment: I have created one here with the "All features & styles" cloudfire links and don't seem to be getting a tip at all now http://jsfiddle.net/KgSqV/3/

Comment: Ah that's because the actual site I'm working on is HTTPS; I didn't realise this would screw up the JSFiddle. I've got the tip working on my site now, although the box is yellow and the tip is purple! Thanks

Comment: multiple the custom download build tries did not worked for me.finally i downloaded full version from CDN and then host it locally and worked

Answer (score 9):

You should select the `Speech bubble 'tips'` option when you make a custom qTip2 build at its download page. If you do not select it your tooltips will be without arrows.